# Automate Outlook on Mac with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, outlook

I can automate Outlook on windows with win32/COM, but does anyone know of a pure python way to do the same on mac osx?

A simple use case would be:

- Open outlook/connect to the active instance
- Launch a blank new email

I want to create an app to create email templates and attach files, then let the user finish editing the email and send when ready, NOT just send emails.

Is there a python wrapper for applescript that may work? (I don't know anything about applescript, so an example would help).

Comment: Related (marked as a duplicate of this one): [\[SO\]: Install win32com on MacOs and Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64975918/4788546).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

@ajrwhite adding attachments had one trick, you need to use 'Alias' from mactypes to convert a string/path object to a mactypes path. I'm not sure why but it works.

here's a working example which creates messages with recipients and can add attachments:

```
from appscript import app, k
from mactypes import Alias
from pathlib import Path

def create_message_with_attachment():
    subject = 'This is an important email!'
    body = 'Just kidding its not.'
    to_recip = ['myboss@mycompany.com', 'theguyih8@mycompany.com']

    msg = Message(subject=subject, body=body, to_recip=to_recip)

    # attach file
    p = Path('path/to/myfile.pdf')
    msg.add_attachment(p)

    msg.show()

class Outlook(object):
    def __init__(self):
    self.client = app('Microsoft Outlook')

class Message(object):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, subject='', body='', to_recip=[], cc_recip=[], show_=True):

        if parent is None: parent = Outlook()
        client = parent.client

        self.msg = client.make(
            new=k.outgoing_message,
            with_properties={k.subject: subject, k.content: body})

        self.add_recipients(emails=to_recip, type_='to')
        self.add_recipients(emails=cc_recip, type_='cc')

        if show_: self.show()

    def show(self):
        self.msg.open()
        self.msg.activate()

    def add_attachment(self, p):
        # p is a Path() obj, could also pass string

        p = Alias(str(p)) # convert string/path obj to POSIX/mactypes path

        attach = self.msg.make(new=k.attachment, with_properties={k.file: p})

    def add_recipients(self, emails, type_='to'):
        if not isinstance(emails, list): emails = [emails]
        for email in emails:
            self.add_recipient(email=email, type_=type_)

    def add_recipient(self, email, type_='to'):
        msg = self.msg

        if type_ == 'to':
            recipient = k.to_recipient
        elif type_ == 'cc':
            recipient = k.cc_recipient

        msg.make(new=recipient, with_properties={k.email_address: {k.address: email}})
```

Comment: One question - why use Path, when you convert it to the string path anyway before passing to Alias?

Comment: @ajrwhite it isn't necessary, but Path is a good way in general to keep filepaths object-oriented.

Comment: Unfortunatley appscript is no longer in active development since 2012 and, no way of knowing how long it will keep working

Comment: Question in 2023: tha above only shows how to create a window of drafts, how to acutally "send" the email out? I've tried to add a send() function in Message class -- it sure send the message but all the formatting in body is gone(the HTML format will not show, so the message will be pure text file like <p>hi this is fake message</p>)

Answer (score 7):

Figured it out using [py-appscript](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/py-appscript/doc_3x/appscript-manual/03_quicktutorial.html)

```
pip install appscript
```

```
from appscript import app, k

outlook = app('Microsoft Outlook')

msg = outlook.make(
    new=k.outgoing_message,
    with_properties={
        k.subject: 'Test Email',
        k.plain_text_content: 'Test email body'})

msg.make(
    new=k.recipient,
    with_properties={
        k.email_address: {
            k.name: 'Fake Person',
            k.address: 'fakeperson@gmail.com'}})

msg.open()
msg.activate()
```

Also very useful to download py-appscript's ASDictionary and ASTranslate tools to convert examples of AppleScript to the python version.

Comment: How would you add an attachment using appscript?

Comment: @ajrwhite see my new answer

Comment: Unfortunatley appscript is no longer in active development since 2012 and, no way of knowing how long it will keep working.. a pity as there seems to be no other way to easily do this on mac

Comment: Looks like the latest release was Jan 23, 2021 according to pypi https://pypi.org/project/appscript/#history

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to edit Jayme’s code to send an email to several recipients, and I finally figured that I just had to repeat the following lines:

```
msg.make(
new=k.recipient,
with_properties={
    k.email_address: {
        k.name: 'Fake Person1',
        k.address: 'fakeperson1@gmail.com'}})

msg.make(
new=k.recipient,
with_properties={
    k.email_address: {
        k.name: 'Fake Person2',
        k.address: 'fakeperson2@gmail.com'}})
```

Comment: Yes you're correct each new recipient needs to be "initialized" with `msg.make` (on Mac only, not Win), but definitely consider creating a function for that action. Have a look at the module I use for Outlook code here: https://github.com/jaymegordo/SMSEventLog/blob/14fcd1747df4e75b2169c246a1976539fd229c25/smseventlog/utils/email.py#L162

*Edit: actually I did include an example with adding multiple recipients already haha, see the accepted answer below!