# Launch Pre configured Outlook email on Mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, py-appscript

i was looking to automate email with outlook, i needed to click a button and open a pre configurated email body, subject and attachment in outlook, this way i could edit or make changes.

Im using Mac OS.

Found this [Automate Outlook on Mac with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61529817/automate-outlook-on-mac-with-python) and this seems to be what i need but im getting errors

Can someone help?

```
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from appscript import app, k
from mactypes import Alias
from pathlib import Path

def create_message_with_attachment():
    subject = 'This is an important email!'
    body = 'Just kidding its not.'
    to_recip = ['test0@hotmail.com', 'test1@gmail.com']

    msg = Message(subject=subject, body=body, to_recip=to_recip)

    # attach file
    file = askopenfilename(initialdir='Downloads/')
    if not file:
        return
    else:
        p = Path(file)
        msg.add_attachment(p)

    msg.show()

class Outlook(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.client = app('Microsoft Outlook')

class Message(object):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, subject='', body='', to_recip=[], cc_recip=[], show_=True):

        if parent is None: parent = Outlook()
        client = parent.client

        self.msg = client.make(
            new=k.outgoing_message,
            with_properties={k.subject: subject, k.content: body})

        self.add_recipients(emails=to_recip, type_='to')
        self.add_recipients(emails=cc_recip, type_='cc')

        if show_: self.show()

    def show(self):
        self.msg.open()
        self.msg.activate()

    def add_attachment(self, p):
        # p is a Path() obj, could also pass string

        p = Alias(str(p)) # convert string/path obj to POSIX/mactypes path

        attach = self.msg.make(new=k.attachment, with_properties={k.file: p})

    def add_recipients(self, emails, type_='to'):
        if not isinstance(emails, list): emails = [emails]
        for email in emails:
            self.add_recipient(email=email, type_=type_)

    def add_recipient(self, email, type_='to'):
        msg = self.msg

        if type_ == 'to':
            recipient = k.to_recipient
        elif type_ == 'cc':
            recipient = k.cc_recipient

        msg.make(new=recipient, with_properties={k.email_address: {k.address: email}})

create_message_with_attachment()
```

Getting this error:

> raise CommandError(self, (args, kargs), e, self.AS_appdata) from e
> appscript.reference.CommandError: Command failed:         OSERROR: -1743
> MESSAGE: The user has declined permission.      COMMAND:
> app('/Applications/Microsoft
> Outlook.app').make(new=k.outgoing_message, with_properties={k.subject:
> 'This is an important email!', k.content: 'Just kidding its not.'})

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the 'new outlook' version of Outlook for Mac? If so, Applescript is not supported.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31465587)