# Automate Outlook and Send Email on Mac with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, email, outlook

I am working on writing a Python script for automate Outlook email in Mac.

From the early Stackoverflow article: [Automate Outlook on Mac with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61529817/automate-outlook-on-mac-with-python), the code works to show Outlook email with attachment, but I need to send the email subsequently.

I added `send_email` with `Send()` operation, and it doesn't work:

```
def create_message_with_attachment():
    subject = 'This is an important email!'
    body = 'Just kidding its not.'
    to_recip = ['myboss@mycompany.com', 'theguyih8@mycompany.com']

    msg = Message(subject=subject, body=body, to_recip=to_recip)

    ...

    msg.send_email()

class Outlook(object):
    def __init__(self):
    self.client = app('Microsoft Outlook')

class Message(object):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, subject='', body='', to_recip=[], cc_recip=[], show_=True):

        if parent is None: parent = Outlook()
        client = parent.client

        self.msg = client.make(
            new=k.outgoing_message,
            with_properties={k.subject: subject, k.content: body})

        .....

    def send_email(self):
        self.msg.Send()

        ....
```

What is the right method to send email? A ton of thanks!

Comment: Try looking at [Send Email via Outlook and SMTP](https://pythonassets.com/posts/send-email-via-outlook-and-smtp/).

Comment: @AliasCartellano I tried the page you recommended, but have trouble when import `from email.message import EmailMessage`. Any other ideas?