# How to "send" email via outlook using python?

Tags: python, outlook, applescript

Accroding to [Automate Outlook on Mac with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61529817/automate-outlook-on-mac-with-python), I've managed to create a *draft* window that can be send after clicking "send" button, however I want this to be completely automatic.

I have implemented new function, but it's not working as expected.

```py
class Message:   # same as above
    ....   
    def send(self):
        self.mail.send()

# modify a bit
def create_message_with_attachment(to_recip: str | list,
                                   body: str, 
                                   subject: str = SUBJECT,
                                   attachment: str = ATTACHMENT_PATH):
    mail = Email(subject=subject, body=body, to_recip=to_recip)

    # attach file, can only pass in Path obj
    mail.add_attachment(Path(attachment))

    mail.show()    # shows the draft window, the format here is ALRIGHT!!
    mail.send()    # <= I want the message to be directly send out instead of making a draft window, if I do this however the body is in plain html text
```

This **does** send the email out. However the message in the body will be completely pure text instead of HTML formatted text.

i.e.

```py
create_message_with_attachment(to_recip: "test@gamil.com", body: "<p>hello</p>", subject: "subject", attachment: "path/to/attachment")
```

the received email body would be `<p>hello</p>` instead of just `hello`.

Comment: *pyhton*: Seriously!?