# Add multiple files to Outlook email using Python

Tags: python-3.x, email, outlook, email-attachments, py-appscript

I want to send an Outlook email with multiple attachments from Python.

I referenced the following code [Automate Outlook on Mac with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61529817/automate-outlook-on-mac-with-python)

```
def add_attachment(self, p):
        # p is a Path() obj, could also pass string

        p = Alias(str(p)) # convert string/path obj to POSIX/mactypes path

        attach = self.msg.make(new=k.attachment, with_properties={k.file: p})
```

When trying to add attachments, the same file is added multiple times instead of different files.

I tried passing the different attachments as a list and iterated over it to add each attachment.

```
def add_attachment(self, attachments):
        # p is a Path() obj, could also pass string
        # convert string/path obj to POSIX/mactypes path
        for attachment in attachments:
            p = Alias(str(attachment))
            attach = self.msg.make(new=k.attachment, with_properties={k.file: p})
```